# Azure Pipelines convert YAML template parameter containing variable to JSON does not escape backslash in variable

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I am transferring a YAML object as a template parameter. The parameter contains a variable with backslashes. Using the [convertToJson YAML expression function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#converttojson) to marshal it

I have simplified my pipeline to:

```
    pool:
      vmImage: windows-latest
    steps:
      - template: template.yml
        parameters:
          struct:
            file1: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\file1.txt
            file2: c:\source\file2.txt
```

With template:

```
parameters:
- name: struct
  type: object
steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: inline
    script: |
      $json = '${{ convertToJson(parameters.struct) }}'
      Write-Host "Serialized JSON: '$json'"
      # From here it fails
      $struct = $json | ConvertFrom-Json
      Write-Host "file1: $($struct.file1)"
```

I get output

```
Serialized JSON: '{
  "file1": "D:\a\1\s\\file1.txt",
  "file2": "c:\\source\\file2.txt"
}'
ConvertFrom-Json : Unrecognized escape sequence. (19): {
  "file1": "D:\a\1\s\\file1.txt",
  "file2": "c:\\source\\file2.txt"
}
At D:\a\_temp\5f5d7778-9828-46cd-aee2-784f969bd822.ps1:10 char:19
+ $struct = $json | ConvertFrom-Json
+                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Not all backslashes were escaped correctly to double backslash. It seems like it first converts to JSON with correct escaping and then substitutes the variable.

I expected the full path to be escaped correctly. I know I can fix this problem by ugly Powershell workarounds. But first I would like to know if this is expected behavior, and secondly if there is nice YAML solution for this.

I have tried

- Using runtime evaluation $[ variables[...] ]
- Using an extra variable wrapping it all variables: path: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\file1.txt and then file1: $(path)
- Using env: to convert the parameter to a Powershell environment variable
- Using ${{format(...)}} to evaluate variable early but Build.SourcesDirectory is not defined at compile time

Comment: I don't know if this is the issue, but `Build.SourcesDirectory` is a [predefined variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables-devops-services) and the `$()` is a textual substitution syntax for predefined variables. It is not YAML and it is not PowerShell -- which is very confusing. It may be that `convertToJson` is returning `"$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\\file1.txt"` and then the predefined variable substitution is performed. Do the alternate things you have tried cover that possibility?

Comment: Yes I think you are right, as I wrote:  "It seems like it first converts to JSON with correct escaping and then substitutes the variable". 
Is this expected behavior? Can I do something in YAML to fix it?